# Is it reasonable to copy-edit questions that are already understandable?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I notice quite a few questions that have grammatical problems but are still understandable. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309553/how-to-open-a-project-in-eclipse):

> i downloaded a zip file of LISTViewTutorial, with all files, but i
>   dont kno how to open it in eclipse, as it just opens the file, not
>   whole project....
>
> and i downloaded it from here
>
> http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/list-view-tutorial-for-android/
>   thanks lot

Here's [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669935/sql-query-select-if-list-is-empty/42670133#42670133):

> i have a question with sql query. In this case i need to get the users
>   which last history activity was 14 days ago, but my history is empty,
>   how i can do something like: if email history is empty on period 14
>   days, select without email history

Is it appropriate to edit questions like these to improve their readability even though it is already possible to figure out what's being asked?

Comment: The surprise is that you thought it necessary to ask.  The point of editing is to make the adequate good and the good better.  If there's a problem that you can fix, fix it — subject to constraints about not changing the intent of the question or invalidating existing answers gratuitously.  (If an answerer has misunderstood the question, an edit may make that clearer.)  It's a question of respecting the effort already put in by other people.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. If a question is on-topic and understandable, it is perfectly fine to edit it to fix spelling, capitalization, and make it better in general.

Please try to fix *all* issues with the post in a single edit. This is especially important if you don't have [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and your edits have to be approved by other community members.

Notes:

- When suggesting an edit, you will probably want to clarify in the edit summary why you decided to fix an old question (*e.g.*, "update spelling on popular (15k views) question"). This will ensure that the edit is more positively received.
- "Understandable" is not necessarily the same thing as "on-topic". If editing won't make the question on-topic, then it is better to let the original poster fix that part first, especially when you don't have full editing privileges (see ["don't polish turd"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=don%27t+polish+turd) discussions).
- Similarly, if you don't have full editing privileges, avoid editing questions that are unlikely to be useful in the future. For instance, your first example has ~15k views, so an edit would definitely benefit a lot of people. The second example is far less likely to be visited in the future (with ~120 views in 5 months). Sticking to making valuable edits keeps the edit review queue smaller and more meaningful, as well as lessens the chances of your edit being regarded as "too minor".

Comment: Also, fixing common typos might help search engines in matching them with the search queries.

Comment: While I (partially) agree with the third point, I don't think whether edits are approved would be affected much (if at all) by adding text like "on a popular (15k views) question" to the edit summary. This is more of a problem when someone makes many such edits over a short period of time, because at that point it's not just a case of someone running into a post that could be improved (which is mostly fine, even if it's not that popular), but rather someone intentionally seeking out old posts to edit (which is less fine). Part of the problem is flooding the front page with old questions.

Answer (score 11):

I think if your goal is to help examples like the ones in the question actually have a higher chance of getting good answers, then beyond it just being reasonable to copy edit examples like those, you *should* edit those kinds of examples if you can afford the time.

The reason is that I think that for better or worse there are probably a significant number of SO users who when they see things like *i* instead of *I* or *kno* instead of *know* are just going to stop right there and not bother to read any further.

I guess it could be argued that we should all try to look past minor capitalization and punctuation errors and whatnot but the reality is that of course we all have a very limited amount of time to spend helping each other here, and when people asking questions have not themselves taken time to do simple things like capitalizing where they should, it kind of gives the impression that maybe they don’t value the time of others here enough to put effort into making their questions more readable, and reduces our motivation for spending any part of own time budget trying to help them.

But in those cases, if the content of the question is otherwise good, I think it’s a socially positive thing for those users and for the community to make it into a learning lesson for them by doing the edits they should have made themselves but—very importantly—also including in the edit summary a good description of why you took time to make the edits; for example:

> Tweaks to ensure others take time to read, and to improve chances of getting a good answer

I think it can also be helpful for those users if you add a separate comment saying the same thing but expanding on it a bit. But minimally the edit summary should at least try to make it clear.

Answer (score 8):

English is a difficult language for many readers (and writers) of Stack Overflow. That is one contributing reason to why some questions are poorly written. People with a good understanding of English may be able to understand a question with poor spelling, poor grammar, and poor punctuation, but many will find it challenging. Editing a question or answer to improve its readability so that all readers—including those who need to frequently refer to a dictionary—can understand it is helpful to the whole community.

Edit away. Fix spelling, grammar, and punctuation. But please fix *all* of the issues you see in the post. Finally, read it again and check that you have fixed everything before submitting your edits.

Answer (score -4):

Well.. I see you are not someone that doesn't understand (based on your reputation) but in those particular examples maybe you didn't get the questions, everybody has bad days. The first one: you can open zip files in eclipse ([downloading zip code example](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fsamples%2Fsamples.html))

The second one looks like a standard query... Select * from log-table where log-table.email="mail@example.com" and log-table.date < (date.now - 15).... I'm so sorry by this example I don't remember very well the data manipulation language.

I must add that there are clear points about downvote questions and the second one deserves it. There's not a basic research about how to, so... sorry figure it out by yourself

Comment: How was this meant to answer the question?

Comment: That last comment you left (now deleted) was totally inappropriate for Stack Overflow. Please avail yourself of your [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy. Yes, it applies on Meta, too.

Comment: Just press the ANSWER button

Comment: 17 people found relevant "is it reasonable copy-edit questions understandable".. I'm sure you have the "winner" answer.